# How to get hasMany relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

Pls bear with me . I am working on api with laravel :

The Idea is that I have table called ( cards ) this table contain column called ( **service_id** ) . 
this column has relation with table ( services ).

This is cards database structure in image :

[image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArPg2.png)

All thing is good with add one service_id , but now I need to make table cards **hasMany** services

So How can I do it , and the database structure what will be?

this is my old code to add new card :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'user_id' => 'required|unique:cards|exists:users,id',
        'service_id' => 'required',
        'numPhone' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
    ],[],[
        'user_id' => '( User id )',
        'service_id' => 'service id',
        'numPhone' => 'Phone Number',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return $this->apiRespone(null,$validator->errors()->all(),'Some input required');
    }    
    $card = Card::create($request->all());
    return $this->apiRespone(new cardResource($card),'Add card Successfully',201);
}
```

Comment: Hello!

I think you are confusing hasMany with BelongsToMany.

Can you please share your relation code on the Card class here?

Comment: @GuilhermeAssemany Hi! No I just don't know how to convert single service to has many services in cards table ! got it ? there is no problem with the relation :(

Comment: I think its not very clear... I understand you need to make cards -> hasMany -> Services. But your DB structure allows you to make cards -> belongsToMany-> Services. 

One other thing that is pretty good to know is that when you use belongsTo and belongsToMany you're telling Laravel that this table holds the foreign key that connects it to the other table.

And of course hasOne and hasMany is telling Laravel that this table does not have the foreign key

Comment: @GuilhermeAssemany the all story is that I had this table as in image each card contains just service_id  , and I did it like in code blew and all things is good for one service , and I had create relation belongsTo for card model . So now I need to make each one of card contains many service . got it sir ? ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create pivot table "cards_services" that has column **id, card_id, service_id column** and used relationship Sync() method of laravel to store/update.

In cards modal

```
public function services(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Service','cards_services', 'card_id', 'service_id');
}
```

For save it.

```
$cards->services()->sync([1,2]); //1 and 2 is service ID and $cards is card modal object
```

Comment: Its not about the postman or web, After `$card = Card::create($request->all());` this line add `$card->services()->sync([Ids array as mentioned in above]);`. 

First remove service_id from cards table and create `cards_services` table, modal as mentioned

Comment: just ask about it cuz it's part of him , now in web it's easy like select box or some like that , but how will be on postman :(

Comment: send as `{"service_id": [1,2], "numPhone": 123456}` in `body` `raw` section and set type as `json` using post method

Comment: I NEEd your advice for this idea ( I will make service_id as array contains ids of services ) What do u thing ?

Comment: sir I have simple question may I ask?

Answer (score 0):

here you have service_id in your cards table

so i think it will be easier to implement service hasMany cards and cards belongsTo service

add this in your service model

```
public function cards(){return $this->hasMany('App\Cards');}
```

add this in your cards model

```
public function service(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');}
```

Note: please rewrite path and Model name according to your requirement

Comment: I already did this , but how will be when I Add new card . I want to contains each card many services ):

Comment: in that condition you can add new pivot table with "card_id" and "service_id" as two columns to store the information about cards having services